# What is the correctly way to delete edges with orientdb OGM in django rest framework?

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework, orientdb, pyorient

I don't know how to create a method to delete edges in django rest framework, using orientdb OGM.

I'm using `pyorient==1.5.5` and `OrientDB 3.0.18` version.

I have two vertex Classes: `ousers`, `ocompany`. Also I have two relationships (edges) Classes: `ofriends`, `oworksat`. So for example:

To make a `ofriends` relationship, I need two `ousers`.
And to make a `oworksat` relationship, I need one `ouser` and one `ocompany`.
Every relationship has it own cluster id.

I know that I can access to these functions:

```
(Pdb) dir(graph)
```

['PROPERTY_TYPES', '_GROOVY_GET_DB', '_GROOVY_NULL_LISTENER', '_GROOVY_TRY', '**class**', '**delattr**', '**dict**', '**dir**', '**doc**', '**eq**', '**format**', '**ge**', '**getattribute**', '**gt**', '**hash**', '**init**', '**le**', '**lt**', '**module**', '**ne**', '**new**', '**reduce**', '**reduce_ex**', '**repr**', '**setattr**', '**sizeof**', '**str**', '**subclasshook**', '**weakref**', '_last_cred', '_last_db', '_last_user', 'batch', 'both', 'bothE', 'build_mapping', 'clear_registry', 'client', 'coerce_class_names', 'coerce_class_names_to_quoted', 'compute_all_properties', 'config', 'create_all', 'create_class', 'create_edge', 'create_edge_command', 'create_function', 'create_props_mapping', 'create_vertex', 'create_vertex_command', **'delete_vertex'**, **'delete_vertex_command'**, 'drop', 'drop_all', 'drop_class', 'edge_from_record', 'edges_from_records', 'element_from_link', 'element_from_record', 'elements_from_links', 'elements_from_records', 'export', 'get_edge', 'get_element', 'get_vertex', 'gremlin', 'guard_reserved_words', 'inE', 'in_', 'include', 'init_broker_for_class', 'list_superclasses', **'ocompany'**, **'ofriends'**, 'open', **'ousers'**, 'out', 'outE', **'oworksat'**, 'populate', 'property_from_schema', 'props_from_db', 'props_to_db', 'query', 'registry', 'save_element', 'scripts', 'server_version', 'strict', 'toposort_classes', 'valid_element_base', 'vertex_from_record', 'vertexes_from_records']

If I do:

```
graph.delete_vertex("#21:0")
```

It works good and deletes #21:0 `ouser` vertex row, which is part of `ofriends` and `oworskat` relationships, so also, that command deletes the relationship where that vertex is included. Obviously, I don't want to delete the entire vertex, just only the specific edge (not the class, just the relationship row).

**I was wondering if exists some command like delete_edge(), but dir(graph) don't tell me nothing related.**

settings.py

```
from pyorient.ogm import Graph, Config
from pyorient.serializations import OrientSerialization
from pyorient.ogm import declarative

BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

config = RawConfigParser()
config.read(BASE_DIR + '/settings.ini')

ORIENTDB = {
    'NAME': config.get('orientdbConf', 'DB_NAME'),
    'USER': config.get('orientdbConf', 'DB_USER'),
    'PASSWORD': config.get('orientdbConf', 'DB_PASS'),
    'HOST': config.get('orientdbConf', 'DB_HOST'),
    'PORT': config.get('orientdbConf', 'DB_PORT'),
}

Config.from_url('plocal://'+ORIENTDB['HOST']+':'+str(ORIENTDB['PORT'])+'/'+ORIENTDB['NAME']+'',''+ORIENTDB['USER']+'', ''+ORIENTDB['PASSWORD']+'',initial_drop=False,serialization_type=OrientSerialization.Binary)
graph = Graph(Config.from_url(''+ORIENTDB['HOST']+'/'+ORIENTDB['NAME']+'',''+ORIENTDB['USER']+'', ''+ORIENTDB['PASSWORD']+'',initial_drop=False))
Node = declarative.declarative_node()
Relationship = declarative.declarative_relationship()
```

models.py

```
from core.settings import Node,Relationship,graph
from pyorient.ogm.property import (String, Date, DateTime, Decimal, Double,
    Integer, Boolean, EmbeddedMap, EmbeddedSet,Link, UUID)

class OUsers(Node):
    element_plural = 'ousers'
    postgresql_id=Integer(nullable=False,unique=True)

class OCompany(Node):
    element_plural = 'ocompany'
    postgresql_id=Integer(nullable=False,unique=True)

class OFriends(Relationship):
    label = 'ofriends'
    from_postgresql_ouser_id=Integer(nullable=False,unique=True)
    to_postgresql_ouser_id=Integer(nullable=False,unique=True)

class OWorksAt(Relationship):
    label = 'oworksat'
    from_postgresql_ouser_id=Integer(nullable=False,unique=True)
    to_postgresql_ocompany_id=Integer(nullable=False,unique=True)

graph.create_all(Node.registry)
graph.create_all(Relationship.registry)
```

serializers.py

```
from .models import (OUsers,OCompany,OFriends,OWorksAt)
from rest_framework import serializers
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
User = get_user_model()

class OFriendsSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    from_postgresql_ouser_id = serializers.IntegerField()
    to_postgresql_ouser_id = serializers.IntegerField()

    def create(self, data):
        return OFriends.objects.create(**data)

    def update(self, instance, data):
        instance.from_postgresql_ouser_id = data.get("from_postgresql_ouser_id")
        instance.to_postgresql_ouser_id = data.get("to_postgresql_ouser_id")
        instance.save()
        return instance

class OFriendsSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    from_postgresql_ouser_id = serializers.IntegerField()
    to_postgresql_ouser_id = serializers.IntegerField()

    def create(self, data):
        return OFriends.objects.create(**data)

    def update(self, instance, data):
        instance.from_postgresql_ouser_id = data.get("from_postgresql_ouser_id")
        instance.to_postgresql_ouser_id = data.get("to_postgresql_ouser_id")
        instance.save()
        return instance
```

api.py

```
class OFriendsViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):

    def destroy(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        queryset = graph.ofriends.query()
        import pdb;pdb.set_trace()
        # HERE should be the command
```

Answer (score 1):

According with the [pyorient OGM documentation](https://github.com/mogui/pyorient/blob/master/OGM.md), that functionality was never added. I already created an [issue](https://github.com/mogui/pyorient/issues/284) in the repository.

So at the moment, I solved my problem using pyorient client, with raw query:

pyorient_client.py

```
from core.settings import ORIENTDB
import pyorient

def orientdbConnection():
    """Orientdb client connection"""
    client = None
    try:
        client = pyorient.OrientDB(ORIENTDB['HOST'], int(ORIENTDB['PORT']))
        session_id = client.connect( ORIENTDB['USER'], ORIENTDB['PASSWORD'] )
        if client.db_exists( ORIENTDB['NAME'], pyorient.STORAGE_TYPE_MEMORY ):
            client.db_open( ORIENTDB['NAME'], ORIENTDB['USER'], ORIENTDB['PASSWORD'])
    except Exception as e:
        print ("[ ERROR ] Fail orientdb connection. Error: " + str(e))
    return client
```

And in the api.py

```
from rest_framework import status
from rest_framework.response import Response
from core.pyorient_client import *

class OFriendsViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):

    def destroy(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        client = orientdbConnection()

        client.command("delete edge ofriends where @rid = '" + kwargs['pk'] + "'")

        return Response(status=status.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT)
```

Maybe this could be useful for anyone else. Note that I receive o'friends @rid as a parameter (by passing the id in DELETE method in swagger UI).

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to constructing the command yourself is to use `Graph.record_delete()` and passing it the record ID of the edge to delete.

The code snippet below assume that `db` is an instance of `OrientDB` and `rid` holds the record ID of the link to delete:

```
cluster = rid[1:].split(':')[0]
record = rid[1:].split(':')[1]
db.record_delete(cluster, record)
```

As a sidebar, the more I work with OrientDB, the more I regret my choice of database given the lack of support for the Python driver which is functionally incomplete and now also very out of date.